# How to get the xml Element having optional value minOccurs=0

Tags: c#, linq

Hi i need to Filter the Xml element having Optional value minOccurs=0
this is what i had Tried

```
    var XMLDocumentMaster = XDocument.Load(@"D:\Stephen\Documents\Schema\AgileFlow_Import.xsd");
    XMLDocumentM = XMLDocumentMaster();
    var prefix = XMLDocumentMaster.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("xs");
    // get Vehicle
    var vehicle = XMLDocumentMaster.Root.Element(prefix + "element");
    // get sequence for Ford
    var sections = vehicle.Element(prefix + "complexType")
                        .Element(prefix + "sequence")
                        // the Ford element
                        .Element(prefix + "element")
                        .Element(prefix + "complexType")
                        .Element(prefix + "sequence")
                        // elements
                        .Elements(prefix + "element").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> objdec = new List<string>();
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"D:\Stephen\Documents\Schema\AgileFlow_Import.xsd");
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//xs:element[@name='IR_DocumentMaster']//xs:complexType//xs:all//xs:element", nsmgr);
        try
        {
            objdec = nodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Where(node =>  node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("minOccurs") != null && node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("minOccurs").Value == "0")
                           .Select(x => x.Attributes["name"].Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
 var XMLDocumentMaster = XElement.Load(@"D:\Stephen\Documents\Schema\AgileFlow_Import.xsd");  
    IEnumerable<XElement> items =  
        from el in XMLDocumentMaster.Descendants("minOccurs")  
        select el;  
    foreach(XElement Ovaule in items)  
       if(Ovaule=0)Console.WriteLine(Ovaule.Name + ":" + (string) Ovaule);
```